# Populate Joomla Calendar field by jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am trying to populate the calendar form field by using jQuery based on the values of other field. I am using `JHTML::calendar` for this. When the value is set via `php` everything works fine for me. But when I try to set it via `jQuery`, it shows the value but when hit submit, the field becomes blank. Although, when I use tab (or focus) then date value saves properly.

Following is my code -

**Via PHP**

```
<?php if($session->get('ssdate')): $dateValue = $session->get('ssdate'); endif; ?>
<?php echo JHTML::calendar($dateValue, 'sdate', 'sdate', '%d-%m-%Y'); ?>
```

**Via jQuery**

```
//data.match_date is in format 01-10-2017
jQuery('#rq_form input[name=sdate]').val(data.match_date);
```

I referred to this post and tried chaning the format to yyyy-mm-dd and set the value but again it goes blank.

> Reference: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2755

**Change date format and set value**

```
var d = new Date(jQuery('#rq_form input[name=sdate]').val()),
var dateValue = d.split("-").reverse().join("-");
//dateValue format = 2017-10-01

jQuery('#rq_form input[name=sdate]').val(dateValue);
```

Comment: Are you sure the query selector you're using (`$('#rq_form input[name=sdate]')`) is correct? Try console logging this to see if it actually exists

Comment: yes it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a change in the calendar widget in Joomla 3.8. In addition to the setting the value via val(), I also had to set the data-alt-value attribute as well. Otherwise it would fail validation. So, in your example,

```
jQuery('#rq_form input[name=sdate]').val(dateValue);
jQuery('#rq_form input[name=sdate]').attr('data-alt-value',dateValue);
```

Comment: When accessing `data-` attributes with jquery, it is simpler/cleaner to use `.data('alt-value', dateValue)`.  Furthermore,  if you use `attr()` or `prop()` to overwrite the value, then try to access `data-alt-value` downscript, you may not get the updated value.  I strongly recommend the [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to do what you're looking for, but its a bit hacky!

When you call `JHtml::_( 'calendar', . .` Joomla renders a div with the class 'field-calendar' into your document, and adds `media/system/js/fields/calendar.js` to the head. The JavaScript then creates `JoomlaCalendar` objects called `_joomlaCalendar` and adds them to all divs with class 'field-calendar'.

If you can get hold of the div with class 'field-calendar', then you can get and manipulate the `_joomlaCalendar` object, setting the date and time. Using jQuery, this would look like:

```
var calendarDiv = jQuery('.field-calendar')[0];
var calendar = calendarDiv._joomlaCalendar;
calendar.setDate( new DateTime('2018-12-12 12:00') );
```

If you take a look at media/system/js/fields/calenar.js, you'll see what methods JoomlaCalendar has and get some idea how you might interact with it.

I say this is hacky because I've no idea the 'correct' way to interact with the JoomlaCalendar JavaSript object. I've successfully manipulated it in various ways, but I don't know if what I was doing was correct.